# Extracting information from survfit object into a table

Tags: r, extract, survival-analysis

I am working on the lung data from the survival package in R. I was able to fir the survival function by sex, but I was not able to extract the information I need from the summary results. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198584/r-extract-summary-table-from-survfit-with-strata) post to extract a table from the survfit data. Here's what I have:

```
library(survival)

lung <- lung

lung_sex <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
res <- summary(lung_sex) 

str(res)
cols <- lapply(c(2:6, 8:11) , function(x) res[x])
tbl <- do.call(data.frame, cols)
```

I would like to create a new column (surv_value) in my "lung" data that contains the corresponding values in the survival column in the summary results. For example, if a person has sex == 1 and time == 11, the surv_value column would contain the value 0.9783. For someone with sex == 2 and time == 5, surv_value would be 0.9889. Finally, for those whose status == 1 (censored), the surv_value should be 1.

I created the column in the "lung" dataset and populated it with 0 for those who were censored with the code:

```
lung <- lung %>%
  mutate(surv_value = ifelse(status == 1, 1, NA))
```

How can I extract the values from "tbl" into "lung" in the correct order?

Comment: This would be a left join where `lung` is your left data set and `tbl` is your right data set.  It would look something like `left_join(lung, tbl, by = join_by(sex = strata, time))`. However the problem is that `tbl$strata` has values like "sex=1" and is a factor variable, whereas `lung$sex` is a numeric variable. So, you'll have to reconcile the merge variables and then touch up the censored data by assigning a "1" to them like your `mutate` expression.